# How to remove comma from column values of each csv and then merge?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have multiple CSVs which I want to merge on certain columns. But before that I need to ensure the column values don't have any commas. So the commas should be replaced by a white space(`" "`).

So I have a folder that contains the CSVs. I am able to load them and merge them on columns `town`, `city` and `state`. So this is what I do

```
os.chdir('/Users/cho/Downloads/census/')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f.endswith('csv') 
df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['town', 'city', 'state']), dfs)
df.to_csv('multicsv.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

But I also I want to include the additional operation of replacing commas with space for each column values. I know I can do it separately by doing something like

```
# I get the list of columns for each dataframe
cols = ['col1', 'col2', ..., 'colN']

# pass them to df.replace(), specifying each char and it's replacement:
df[cols] = df[cols].replace({'\$': '', ',': ''}, regex=True)
```

But how do I include this step as part of merging operation?

Answer (score 2):

I think better is replace values in list comprehension for create list of DataFrames `dfs`:

```
os.chdir('/Users/cho/Downloads/census/')

cols = ['col1', 'col2', ..., 'colN']
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f).replace({'\$': '', ',': ''}, regex=True) 
          for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f.endswith('csv')]

df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['town', 'city', 'state']), dfs)
df.to_csv('multicsv.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```